# plot ROC curve from glm model using gaussian model

Tags: prediction, inference, roc

I have some data (322 x 4) that looks like that

```
> mydata

       MFI disease    sex age      
1 11.44882    Ctrl    Man  65
2 11.77361    Ctrl    Man  57
3 11.75761    Ctrl  Woman  47
4 11.70108    Ctrl    Man  60
5 12.31313    Ctrl  Woman  66
6 12.44899    Ctrl  Woman  54
```

I have tested using a linear model if there is a statistical significance on fluorescence levels (MFI column) between control (Ctrl) and Case groups. What I would like to do is plot a ROC curve from the linear model I am using. Here is my code:

```
library(pROC)
myglm <- glm(MFI ~ disease + sex + age, data = mydata, family = "gaussian")
pred=predict(myglm,type=c("response"))
mydata$pred
roccurve <- roc(disease ~ pred, data = mydata)
plot(roccurve)
```

I would like to know if I am doing the right thing,

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your interest lies in determining whether there is a difference between mean fluorescence levels in cases and controls, then you should consider a basic test of group differences. A t-test would be perfectly reasonable for a dataset with more than 300 observations.

That is simply a matter of inference. Prediction, on the other hand, would require you to calculate some more detailed measures, and it brings into question whether you've appropriately modeled these data.

The ROC is concerned with a *binary* prediction only. That is if MFI, your fluorescence variable, were coded using 0/1 to present the absence or presence of fluorescence (or certain detectable levels thereof), you can determine the predictive value of the `glm`. In your example, it doesn't seem that these data take that form. Mathematically, if you calculate an ROC for a continuous variable it is equivalent to a somewhat complicated U-shaped statistic that doesn't have much to do with predictive accuracy for continuous variables.

If that were the case, the model would be a poor model choice for a few reasons. Namely, a Gaussian model does not take advantage of the fact that such data are bounded between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks @AdamO, I have used a linear model because I would like to correct for age and sex, since they are important covariates in my model. I was thinking about using a logistic regression coding Ctrl as 0 and Case as 1 and then doing `glm(disease~MFI+age+sex, family="binomial"`, although in this case the hypothesis is different, isn't it? My final aim is to know if the levels of MFI might be used as a good predictor to differentiate between Cases and Controls, thus, I thought in using a ROC curve

Comment: @user2380782 I see, so you're considering MFI to be a risk factor. That's fine. As you may know, there are large differences between *predicting* a binary outcome and *assessing an association* with a binary outcome. ROCs are indeed good for the former, but only in the context of developing a more refined prediction model. What you are saying is a familiar story from the social sciences where "predict" is often used interchangeably with "is associated with": a very important distinction in biostatistics. I would rely on a test of association for the odds ratio for MFI as the comparison.

Comment: @user2380782 as with linear regression, very good predictors may not have strong associations, and vice versa. It all is a function of the data structure and it's important to present $2 \times 2$ contingency tables to convey this to the reader(s). Low prevalence of disease and outcome often leads to inference that a risk factor is not a good predictor, but is highly associated with the outcome. Take cancer epidemiology: rare genetic expressions do not often wind up in risk models, but are shown in logistic models to be strongly associated with cancer risk.

Comment: thanks for the comments and for all your help. I am reading now more about ROC curves and predictors on diseases. Some people find a ROC curve in a group of patients using a panel of biomarkers and then search for replication the same panel in another group of patients calculating again the ROC curve. They compare both AUC in both groups of patients to see if the AUC is statistically significant, some of them use Z-test and others the `roc.test` command for `pROC` package. Do you have a preference? If both group of samples are independent I assume a Z-test can be applied. Thanks again

Comment: @user2380782 do you wish to continue this conversation in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/25627/applied-roc-analysis?tab=general)?

Comment: it would be brilliant, how should I proceed?

Comment: @user2380782 I believe you follow the hyperlinked chat and can contribute there http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25627/applied-roc-analysis

Comment: I am trying to log in but it fails, maybe is a problem with my proxy settings